# How to create a nested mat-table in a table with expandable rows using angular material

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have the below data

```js
[
    {
        "_id": "c9d5ab1a",
        "subdomain": "wing",
        "domain": "aircraft",
        "part_id": "c9d5ab1a",
        "info.mimetype": "application/json",
        "info.dependent": "parent",
        "nested": [
            {
                "domain": "aircraft",
                "_id": "c1859902",
                "info.mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                "info.dependent": "c9d5ab1a",
                "part_id": "c1859902",
                "subdomain": "tail"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "1b0b0a26",
        "subdomain": "fuel",
        "domain": "aircraft",
        "part_id": "1b0b0a26",
        "info.mimetype": "image/jpeg",
        "info.dependent": "no_parent"
    }
]
```

Here if `"info.dependent": "parent"` then it is nested and if `"info.dependent": "no_parent"` then it does not have a child. I tried to create a dynamic table but I am stuck on how to make it collapsible/expandable with a nested table. 
Here is my code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cvjqop).

```html
<mat-table class=" mat-elevation-z8" [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="col" *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ col }} </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element[col] }} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row;columns:displayedColumns"></mat-row>

</mat-table>
```

**.ts**

```js
public data = [
    {
        "_id": "c9d5ab1a",
        "subdomain": "wing",
        "domain": "aircraft",
        "part_id": "c9d5ab1a",
        "info.mimetype": "application/json",
        "info.dependent": "parent",
        "nested": [
            {
                "domain": "aircraft",
                "_id": "c1859902",
                "info.mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                "info.dependent": "c9d5ab1a",
                "part_id": "c1859902",
                "subdomain": "tail"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "1b0b0a26",
        "subdomain": "fuel",
        "domain": "aircraft",
        "part_id": "1b0b0a26",
        "info.mimetype": "image/jpeg",
        "info.dependent": "no_parent"
    }
];

dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);
displayedColumns = ['_id', 'subdomain', 'domain', 'part_id', 'info.mimetype', 'info.dependent'];

constructor(){
    this.displayedColumns = this.displayedColumns;
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
}
```

**Required format** :--> 
**[image: nested table]**

The nested format is like below

> row 1 -->    _id ,subdomain,domain,info.dependent

When we click on that particular row, then it has to expand and display the nested data in a table with the column names and row data.

```js
"nested": [
    {
        "domain": "aircraft",
        "_id": "c1859902",
        "info.mimetype": "image/jpeg",
        "info.dependent": "c9d5ab1a",
        "part_id": "c1859902",
        "subdomain": "tail"
    }
]
```

Comment: Using the Angular Material Example for a table with expandable rows [here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) where are you getting stuck?

Comment: In the example it is.mentioned using separate row names.But here i used dynamic row and column names using ngcontainer and after that mat row and in the example there is only day I want to show both col names and row data also

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Note: For those who want to skip the lengthy explanation, here is the [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table).

What you actually want is to create a nested `mat-table` where all the nested tables are sortable and can be filtered through as well.

Firstly, since you need to use filtering and sorting in your nested table, you need to create a new `MatTableDataSource` for it. This can be done initially when you create the main `dataSource` in the `ngOnInit` like below.

```js
usersData: User[] = [];

USERS.forEach(user => {
    if (user.addresses && Array.isArray(user.addresses) && user.addresses.length) {
        this.usersData = [...this.usersData, { ...user, addresses: new MatTableDataSource(user.addresses) }];
    } else {
        this.usersData = [...this.usersData, user];
    }
});
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.usersData);
```

From the expandable rows [example in the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples), we can see how to create an expandable row. In the expandable row, we will now have a table along with the `Filter` input. We will add some conditions so that the row is expandable only if there are `addresses` present.

```html
<div class="example-element-detail" *ngIf="element.addresses?.data.length"
    [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
    <div class="inner-table mat-elevation-z8" *ngIf="expandedElement">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
        </mat-form-field>
        <table #innerTables mat-table #innerSort="matSort" [dataSource]="element.addresses" matSort>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="{{innerColumn}}" *ngFor="let innerColumn of innerDisplayedColumns">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{innerColumn}} </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[innerColumn]}} </td>
            </ng-container>
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="innerDisplayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: innerDisplayedColumns;"></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now that the row expands only if there are nested elements, we need to get rid of the hover for the users which have no `addresses`

Here is the CSS responsible for adding a `background-color` on hover

```css
tr.example-element-row:not(.example-expanded-row):hover {
    background: #777;
}
```

So we just need to add the `example-element-row` class to our row if the row has an `address`. If it has no address, the row should not be clickable and there should not be a hover which indicates to the user that the row is in fact not clickable.

```html
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;" 
    [class.example-element-row]="element.addresses?.data.length"
    [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
    (click)="toggleRow(element)">
</tr>
```

In `toggleRow`, we will define the logic for what happens when you click a row in the template. We will also implement `sort` when the user clicks on the row in this function.

```js
@ViewChildren('innerSort') innerSort: QueryList<MatSort>;

toggleRow(element: User) {
    element.addresses && (element.addresses as MatTableDataSource<Address>).data.length ? (this.expandedElement = this.expandedElement === element ? null : element) : null;
    this.cd.detectChanges();
    this.innerTables.forEach((table, index) => (table.dataSource as MatTableDataSource<Address>).sort = this.innerSort.toArray()[index]);
}
```

Finally, we need to define the `applyFilter` function so the nested tables can be filtered.

```js
@ViewChildren('innerTables') innerTables: QueryList<MatTable<Address>>;

applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.innerTables.forEach((table, index) => (table.dataSource as MatTableDataSource<Address>).filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase());
}
```

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table).

Comment: your example was good but there are 2 thing s to notice   1) The table has to use the dynamic data bcoz we dont know how many columns or row data will come but in the example for nested one you took static data   2) The format which nested requires is like the sample pic which uploaded in question

Comment: It was not clear at all from your question that you wanted another table on expansion. I just saw the image you added to your question. Btw, would it really make sense to have a `Filter` for the inner table? IMHO, a user can't practically have that many address that you'd need a filter there.

Comment: please check my updated question here requirement was first display the parent row if has a nested data in it then expand the row with col and row data display it as table

Comment: Check out my updated answer and StackBlitz. Note: I have not added a filter as it seems unnecessary IMO. Also, you haven't mentioned anything about a filter in your question except in the image which was later added.

Comment: filter  & selection of rows is required for all how can i do that for that for nested also ?

Comment: You shouldn't be asking so many questions at once in the same post especially since you didn't mention the filter initally. Read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267058/how-to-handle-a-question-that-asks-many-things.

Comment: @nash11, in my answer there is a chat you can join. If you want the 50+ points :D - I give up

Comment: @Dexter - are you having any issues with this answer?

Comment: @nash11: is it possible for you to help to create one more expandable row of address? Example, when I click an address row, it will expand to show, say, rows of company with floor and unit number. I am trying to follow your https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table to make it to have two-level expandable rows but with no success... Thanks

Comment: @Zee - sure it's possible but I must warn you, you might run into performance issues with 3 nested tables. Please create a separate question and direct me to it so I can help you out.

Comment: @nash11. I posted the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59042625/angular-mat-table-3-level-nested-sortable-tables. I hope you don't mind I forked your code with additional nested data level Company. I appreciate your help and time. Thanks.

Comment: current stalkblitz having issue. when user sort immediately on any column once app load, expansion is not working. I have same issue and posted question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63575829/multilevel-mat-table-does-not-expand-to-another-level-after-first-sort. can you help me out?

Comment: @HarshadVekariya - I don't seem to be able to replicate this issue. I followed the steps mentioned. Are you talking about the row with the name `Eugene` specifically? That row does not have any addresses as per the `dataSource`, which is why it is not expanding.

Comment: @nash11: its replicate, just follow same step in my question. Anyway, I just resolved it. its issue with animation. check my update in stack overflow question. Thanks for replying.

Comment: @nash11 how to display multiple tables when click on the table row, your current implementation is showing 1 child table when clicking on the row, if we have multiple child’s (something like tree structure like this https://stackblitz.com/angular/bynykkvyvgd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-flat-overview-example.ts ) how to display them in the separate table with header. I need to display them in a table.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [examples from the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) especially [the one with the expandable row](https://stackblitz.com/angular/goxbbaogrml?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts):

- You are missing the `multiTemplateDataRows` directive in the `<mat-table>`
- The `@detailExpand` trigger is missing
- ...

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b5nr3n) is the example from the docs with your data

**Edit (regarding the comment)**

Here is how you can get the dynamic columns:

Add this to your component

```
  getKeys(object): string[] {
    return Object.keys(object);
  }
```

use the method in the template (template updated according to the attached details screen and the note about the multiple elements under the `nested` key):

```html
<div class="example-element-descriptions">
    <div *ngFor="let nested of element['nested']"
         class="example-element-description">
        <div *ngIf="element['info.dependent'] === 'parent'">
            <div class="example-element-description__header">
                <div class="example-element-description__cell"
                     *ngFor="let key of getKeys(nested)">{{key}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="example-element-description__content">
                <div class="example-element-description__cell"
                     *ngFor="let key of getKeys(nested)">{{element[key]}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="element['info.dependent'] === 'no_parent'">no parent</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your example was good but there are 2 thing s to notice   1) The table has to use the dynamic data bcoz we dont know how many columns or row data will come but in the example for nested one you took static data   2) The format which nested requires is like the sample pic which uploaded in question

Comment: I've uptaded the StackBliitz to use the dynamic columns

Comment: there is one doubt https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-co1v3t  i have updated the json say i have multiple nested objects then bcoz i updated the json and checking with the table but the data it is not displaying

Comment: So there can be more objects in the nested list? Ok

Comment: Is there any possiblity for showing header for first table bcoz for every it is not imp and how can we get the id of all the rows including id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199133/discussion-between-kasptom-and-dexter).