# Multilevel mat-table does not expand to another level after first sort

Tags: html, angular, sorting, hierarchical-data, mat-table

We have been using `multiTemplateDataRows` for multilevel mat-table. Its working fine and we can expand it to multi level. Although, there seems to be one issue in specific scenario.

Scenario:

1. Sort level-1 once application loads data in to the table
2. **click on any row and it will not expand**
3. Again click on another row, it will expand. Now it will expand on every click, issue will no longer exist.

***Its just not working when we expand very first time after sort.***

below is the HTML for level-1:

```
<table mat-table #outerSort="matSort" [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort>
```

and typescript:

```
@ViewChild('outerSort', { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
```

We couldn't found any logs or error in console, so not sure what is issue.

here is stalkblitz for same: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-expand-issuw-when-sort

Answer (score 0):

So, I found an answer.
We have been trying to find issue in data and sort behavior but issue is animation.
Angular Animations setting animation state to void when items are sorted and that what happening.

as a solution either remove animation (if you can) else apply following void in animation path.

```
trigger("detailExpand", [
      state(
        "collapsed, void",
        style({
          height: "0px",
          visibility: "hidden"
        })
      ),
      state(
        "expanded",
        style({
          "min-height": "48px",
          height: "*",
          visibility: "visible"
        })
      ),
      transition(
        "expanded <=> collapsed, void <=> *",
        animate("225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)")
      )
    ])
```

Stalkblitz already updated.

Ref: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13835