# Adding a filter under each column for mat-table

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I came across a Stackblitz from another [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57810336/how-to-create-a-nested-mat-table-in-a-table-with-expandable-rows-using-angular-m/57839402#57839402) and wanted to see if I could add a filter to the parent table for each column.

[Here's my Stackblitz that I tried and this was the closest I could get](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-wsnbey?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html) (please ignore the CSS/styling). I slapped an input filter under the columns. (Note that I haven't implemented the actual working filter itself in the .ts file) I'm noticing something interesting though, that the button to sort the column itself gets wrapped with not only the header/column name, but the filter itself--so when a user clicks on the filter to focus on the field, they'll also trigger a sort.

I tried adding the entire `mat-form-field` block below of the `th`/header tags and it doesn't even work or show up. I'm at a loss here and can't seem to figure out how to place the filters below without having it wrapped in a sort button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent the sort button from being clicked when clicking on the input field, you could try adding `(click)="$event.stopPropagation();"` to the input field. It's also possible that you may need to add that to the `(mouseup)` or `(mousedown)` events instead of the `(click)` event.

Comment: Thanks--a prevent default event is something I've forgotten about after switching over to Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the tag mat-sort-header in the th, use dedicated span in the th.

```
<span mat-sort-header></span>
```

For example , you can write could in your stackblitz example as

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="{{innerColumn}}" *ngFor="let innerColumn of innerDisplayedColumns">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> 
          <span mat-sort-header>{{innerColumn}}</span>
          <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
     </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[innerColumn]}} </td>
 </ng-container>
```

In this way sorting will happen only on the column name, when you click on input, only input's keyup function will be called, sorting will not happen on input textfield click.